# Assign type-module (@type/lodash) to minified localized version of lodash

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an odd scenario where I am trying to take a module that exists on NPM and minify the module. I would however like to preserve types. For instance let's take `lodash` and it's counterpart `@types/lodash`, what I would like to do is have a way that I can take my minified `lodash` let's call it `./min-lodash.ts` and I'd would like to reference `./min-lodash.ts` within my code when I do this, it looses it's typing because these type-modules are defined by namespace which seems to be package name. I would then assume that if I added something like this:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts" />
```

To the top of the file that I would be able to bring in the types from the type-module. But alas this is not the case.

I am looking for a way to basically assign a typed-module definition to an arbitrary file.

Is this possible?

Essentially what I am trying to do is the following (another way of thinking about it):

> lodash.ts

```
import * as lodash from 'lodash'
export = lodash
```

> lodash.d.ts

```
declare const lodash: typeof import('lodash')
export = lodash
```

I am looking for a way to minify both of these files to one file or two new `min-lodash.ts` and `min-lodash.d.ts` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a *very* high chance that you are doing something wrong if this is your workflow and there's a better solution.

That said, there are a couple ways you could do this.

1. Place your minified lodash in `min-lodash.js` and create `min-lodash.d.ts` with the following content:

   ```ts
   declare const lodash: typeof import('lodash')
   export = lodash
   ```

   This is probably the better option since it keeps the type declaration out of the minified file, and will only be used for type inference.
2. Declare the type of the minified bundle in `min-lodash.ts` and use `export =` to generate the export. Whether or not this will work depends on how you are minifying the bundle. If you are creating a UMD bundle, you can add the following to the end of your minified bundle.

   ```ts
   const lodash: typeof import('lodash') = module.exports
   export = lodash
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks for this deep dive. I just tried this https://gist.github.com/reggi/262f7f052951676308e4cae81f5559f4 and it didn't work.

Comment: @ThomasReggi I think you should rename `lodash.ts` to `lodash.js` and change `export = lodash` to `export default lodash` given the linked gist. Difficult to say without a project to clone to look at.